# PL SQL Index, pulling data that has a specific ending

Tags: oracle, plsql

Hi I cannot figure out how to focus my search query to pull data that ends in 0. Any ideas?

> Create a PL/SQL block to retrieve the name of all departments that
>   have a department number that ends in zero from the departments table
>   and print each department name on the screen, incorporating an INDEX
>   BY table.

```
CREATE table depts AS SELECT dept_name FROM emp_departments WHERE
```

... ??

Comment: This should work in your case `CREATE table depts AS SELECT dept_name FROM emp_departments WHERE  substr(dept_number,-1) = 0;`

Comment: @XING Wow so good! <3. Too bad I can't hire you as a tutor on here! :'(

Comment: I guess you need to read some good book on oracle. Such small things even tutor will not teach. They will teach you concepts but logic you need to apply

Answer (score 2):

Like

```
--if deptno is a string 
WHERE deptno like '%0'

--if deptno is a number
WHERE mod(deptno, 10) = 0
```